# Coloring polygons in a vector tile on a map

Tags: leaflet, postgis, vector-tiles, react-leaflet

I have a GeoJSON file corresponding to [blocks](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=Blocks+%282010%29) from the Census website.  I'd like to display them on a map with them shaded a certain color as determined by various data stored in a PostGIS database.  Since blocks are so small, I'd like to use a tile layer to only serve the necessary amount to the client as the entire dataset is way too big (300+ MB).

Is there a way to color polygons individually based on corresponding datapoints either on the client or server side?  I have all the polygons along with their corresponding datapoints stored in a PostGIS database.  I'm using [TileSplash](https://github.com/faradayio/tilesplash) to retreive the polygons and serve up a vector tile layer which then gets rendered by leaflet ([react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet)).  Is this possible to do with a vector tile layer or do I need to use a raster tile layer?